# How can I install SP3 on Win XP without having it save files for uninstallation?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, sp3

I have the SP3 network install file, installing over a pristine original Windows XP installation.

When I run the SP3 install, it spends aeons estimating space for uninstallation and whatnot. I don't care about this and I just wanna get done with it and get back to being a mac snob.

I have System Restore disabled.

How can I make it install without saving all this uninstall crap?

(I have the cab files extracted manually, if it helps at all.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the SP3 install has a command line switch for /nobackup and it will not save any uninstall info if you use it.  There are a few other handy options as well but I think this is the one you want.  An example of the full command line is below.  Simply do a run -> cmd and then change to the directory where your xp sp3 distro is living. Then run the command below (adjusting for patch of course) and you should good to go!

```
C:\Desktop\WindowsXP-KB936929-SP3-x86-ENU /nobackup
```

Answer (score 5):

Run SP3 installation with /nobackup parameter

```
WindowsXP-KB936929-SP3-x86-ENU /nobackup
```

for more parameters

```
WindowsXP-KB936929-SP3-x86-ENU /help
```

Comment: /help doesn't seem to work. It outputs nothing and starts unpacking anyway.

Answer (score 2):

[TechRepublic](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5208-6230-0.html?forumID=102&threadID=262992) has  a complete list of command line options for Windows XP SP3 including /nobackup /norestart and /overwriteoem